# EXM in multisite environment

Tags: exm, multisite

I have a problem with EXM on a multisite environment.
The application has two sites on the CD, e.g. `test.com` and `test-test2.com`.
For each of them is configured ManagerRoot with the corresponding values in the base url.

A subscription mail has a valid start, e.g.
`test-test.com/sitecore modules / web / exm / redirecturlpage.aspx` ...
But after clicking on it, we are redirected to the CM server, e.g. `test.cm/sitecore modules / web / exm / configsubscription`.

Has anyone an idea what this may be due to?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple sites then it is a better solution to create custom hostname mapping. To create a custom hostname mapping, please follow below steps:

1. Go to this location `/sitecore/system/Settings/Email/System/Hostname Mappings`
2. Create new `Hostname Mappings`
3. Insert `Original` and `Public` URL.

For more information, you can follow this link https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/en/link-generation-and-hostname-mapping-in-exm.html

Comment: Hi, I have a follow up question for this one: We have multiple frontends (site1, site2, site3), each of them have their own manager root. They all share the same CM url (cm.site). How am I supposed to map this via hostname mapping? They way I see it works, each cm url only corresponds to a single frontend url (1:1, instead of 1:m)